# Using PagerSlidingTabStrip on a DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, dialogfragment, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using this Library that I found on GitHub

[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

and its awesome. Been using it for sometime now. But recently, I tried to implement this on a DialogFragment and its not working properly. It crashes, and gives me this error

> Unable to find resource ID #0xaba

This is my code

```
    LinearLayout LayerA = (LinearLayout) RootView.findViewById( R.id.llCreateTabParent );
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( -2 , -2);
    LayerA.setLayoutParams( lLayout ); 

    vPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.fManager);
    pager = new ViewPager( getActivity() );
    pager.setId( "VP".hashCode() );
    pager.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( -2,  -2 ) );
    pager.setAdapter( vPagerAdapter );

    tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) RootView.findViewById(R.id.pagerSlidingTabStrip1); 
    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener( this );  
    tabs.setAllCaps( true ); 
    tabs.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);  
    tabs.setTextSize( 20 );
    tabs.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );  
    tabs.setShouldExpand(true); 
    tabs.setTypeface( null, Typeface.BOLD );
    tabs.setIndicatorColor( Color.DKGRAY );
    tabs.setViewPager(pager); 

    LayerA.addView( pager );
```

This code works perfectly when on Activity or FragmentActivity, but for some reason not on DialogFragment. Please if you have some fix or some ways on how to show this PagerSlidingTabStrip on a dialog ( Except Activity themed as Dialog ) please help me. Thanks in advance. any help and idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check your ID or clean and built your project...

Comment: yes, I tried that but the error is still there, the error exactly happens when on  LayerA.addView( pager );

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager()
I dont know for some, this works. 
Thanks anyway.